# WordPress Sub-menu from dropdown to horizontal

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, alignment

> I'm editing the WordPress default theme TwentyTwelve, and I'm stuck in aligning the submenus > from dropdown to horizontal line.
>   Here's the site http://nickart.hostei.com/
>   Here's what it looks like [image]
>   Here's what i want it to look like [image]
>   Here's my style sheet http://pastebin.com/4nLRNR6d
>   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete ALL your menu related items and please insert this instead :

```
/*=Menu*/
#access UL
{
    list-style: none;
}
#access LI
{
    float: left;
}
.menu-item-type-taxonomy A
{
    float: left;
}
.menu-item-type-taxonomy
{
    height: auto;
}
.menu-item-type-taxonomy .sub-menu
{
}
#access A
{
    color: #6A6A6A;
    padding: 0 13px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Ropa Sans", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}
UL .sub-menu
{
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

After that you can continue with your formatting (colors, hovers etc.)